# Simple one way suspend for thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a small project where I have 2 threads `ListenerThread` and `HeartbeatThread` which are both nested classes inside `HeartbeatServer`.

What I have is the listener thread adds clients to `registerClients` when the someone sends a request (The rest is out of scope of this question).

I am looking for a simple way to suspend `HeartbeatThread` when there are no clients in the `registerClients` hashmap.

Originally I was thinking it would be as easy as using an if statement at the top of the while loop in the `ListenerThread` that checks how many clients there are and if the client count is less then zero the `ListenerThread` would call `heartbeatServer.heartbeatThread.wait()` and `heartbeatServer.heartbeatThread.notify()` when the client count is about zero. However when I do this java throws an `IllegalMonitorException`. After doing some digging I found out the exception is because I did not call `wait()` inside of a `synchronized` block.

Since I am looking to only go one way `ListenerThread -> HeartbeatThread` and never any other way how could I accomplish this? Would I still be better off using the `synchronized` block in each thread. If that's the case then I need some clarification what exactly I am synchronizing.

I found this example;

```
boolean ready = false;

// thread 1
synchronized(lock) {
    ready = true;
lock.notifyAll();
}


// thread 2
synchronized(lock) {
    while(!ready) 
        lock.wait();
}
```

This example looks like it would solve me issue. But since I am new to this I am not sure what `lock` is supposed to be.

Could the example be reworked or completed to fit my needs or is there a better way to solve my issue?

**I am not really sure what code would need to be show so I can post anything that is requested.**

**UPDATE**

I think I finally worked out a solution to my issue.
    public class HeartbeatServer {

```
final Object lock = new Object();
volatile Boolean suspended = true;

//TEST USE ONLY
volatile int userCount = 0;

// This is the thread that will send the heartbeats back to the client.
private class HeartbeatThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        HeartbeatServer heartbeatServer = HeartbeatServer.getInstance();

        while (true) {

            synchronized (heartbeatServer.lock) {

                if(suspended) {

                    try {

                        System.out.println("Suspending heartbeat thread!");
                        heartbeatServer.lock.wait();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Resuming heartbeat thread!");

                } // End if block

            } // End synchronized block

            try {

                Thread.sleep(2000L);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        } // End while loop

    } // End run method

} // End HeartbeatThread

// This is the thread that will listen for clients connecting to the server.
private class ListenerThread implements Runnable {

    // The instance of heartbeatServer should be the first object so we can use it everywhere in the class.
    HeartbeatServer heartbeatServer = HeartbeatServer.getInstance();

    private void suspendHeartbeats() {

        synchronized (heartbeatServer.lock) {

            heartbeatServer.suspended = true;

        }

    } // End suspendHeartbeats

    private void resumeHeartbeats() {

        synchronized (heartbeatServer.lock) {

            heartbeatServer.suspended = false;
            heartbeatServer.lock.notify();

        }

    } // End resumeHeartbeats

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {

            if(heartbeatServer.userCount < 1) {

                suspendHeartbeats();

            } else {

                resumeHeartbeats();

            }

        } // End while loop

    } // End run method

} // End ListenerThread

} // End HeartbeatServer
```

Is there anything else I could do to improve my threads? Some of the parts in the HeartbeatThread are left over from testing. But I referring more to the logic used to suspend the HeartbeatThread.

Comment: `lock` can be any private object.  You want it to be private so other classes cannot interfere with your code by synchronizing on it themselves.  In fact, `private static final Object lock = new Object();` is often a good practice.

Comment: So the `lock` is just a thing for the 2 threads to sync up with? So if I wanted to suspend the `HeartbeatThread` I would still call heartbeatServer.heartbeatThread.wait() like I did before but just inside of `synchronized` with a dummy object for the `lock`? Is the correct?

Comment: I would recommend to use java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock as it is more modern and sane alternative for the built-in java locks. It should be much easier to understand for someone who is learning

Comment: heartbeatThread.wait() is not the same lock.wait().  Although every object has its own wait() method, you should not be calling that method on any object other than the object on which you have synchronized.

Comment: The methods are somewhat confusingly named but when you `wait()` on an object (any object, even an object representing another thread), you always suspend **the current thread**.

Comment: If you're implementing a producer/consumer sort of pattern for passing data from one thread to another, consider using a higher-level interface like [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) instead of implementing the synchronization yourself.

Comment: @biziclop so if I call `wait()` in side the listener thread then I am calling wait on that thread specifically?

Answer (score 2):

You sound like you already have found the core of what you need, it is just confidence holding you back.  wait/notify are fairly low level primitives in Java and it is common for there to be a subtle timing bug to creep in when using them.  This is why higher level abstractions like ReadWriteLock, Semaphore etc exist.  There is an example in the Java API docs demonstrating how to block until a condition (such as empty or full) is reached [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html), they have used ReentrantLock and Condition to signal empty/not empty.

Going back to your question about the lock object, it is simply the object that they are calling wait/notify against.  It can be more or less any object so long as it is always the same object.

There is an argument that says that when using synchronized/wait/notify that one should use a private final object and not the publicly exposed object.  The argument is that if the lock object is exposed then other code could themselves call wait/notify/synchronized against it and cause a side effect which could become tricky to track down.  Threaded code is hard anyway, so the argument is aiming to reduce the opportunity for external interference creeping in.  This explains your example, as it is following this convention.

Comment: I would go so far as to say there is next to no reason for anyone to use `wait()/notify()` in newly written code.

Comment: Since the example I posted is no complete I am still unsure what `lock` is. Wouldn't I want to synchronize `ready` in the example instead? Unless I am not understanding the purpose of `synchronized`.

Comment: @ianc1215 Ready is a primitive, it is not an object and thus it has no monitor.  Thus one cannot synchronise against it.

Comment: One synchronises against an object's monitor in order to lock it.  Only one thread may hold a specific monitor at a time.  If only threads that own the lock(aka monitor) can enter the synchronised block of code then only one thread may enter it.  This prevents concurrent running of that code and makes all threads queue to run one at a time.  This is what makes it thread safe, as only one thread may enter the protected region then there are no threading risks within that region.

Comment: @ChrisK. Oh that makes sense so who ever has the lock is the only one who can enter that code block? So one thread grabs the lock to "own" it. The thread does what it needs then unlocks it so another thread can enter?